# dropDownVerticalAlignment top issue on jqxDropDownList inside jqxGrid

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I have been working in an application developed with jqWidget, jquery and HTML5. I have been came across an weird issue with jqxDropDownList inside jqxGrid.

On making `dropDownVerticalAlignment: 'top'`, the data still comes on bottom, that's really weird with jqxDropDownList. May be jqxGrid is controlling something inside that forces jqxDropDownList to open on bottom only.

**Screenshot:**

[image: jqxDropDownList]

---

The data overflows under body. I have tried every combination with jqxDropDownList. I have been using simple code for dropdown. Here,

```
editor.jqxDropDownList({
    source: scan_dropdown,
    //autoDropDownHeight:true,
    //dropDownHeight:200,
    dropDownVerticalAlignment: 'top',
    selectedIndex: 0
});
```

Could anyone help me out..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Grid's DropDownList editor has default settings which cannot be disabled. There is a feature in jqxGrid, which allows you to implement custom editors so you can add custom DropDownList editor with the settings which you prefer for your application.

Comment: Actually adding by custom dropdown creates lot of bugs with selection and hover conditions. So, i am not preferring it. But i don't understand why `dropDownVerticalAlignment: top` doesn't show the dropdown properly.